# What is the relation of fourier series coefficients of a function and its derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

$$F(f′)(ξ)
=\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{−2\pi i\xi} tf′(t)dt \\
=\left.e^{−2\pi i\xi t}f(t)\right\vert^\infty_{t=−\infty}−\int^\infty_{-\infty} −2\pi i\xi e^{−2\pi i\xi t}f(t)dt
=2\pi i\xi\cdot F(f)(\xi)
$$

(The first term must vanish, as we assume $f$ is absolutely integrable on $\mathbb R$.)
This is for fourier transform and we have a similar relation for fourier series. But why is the first term equal to zero in fourier series it will have $1/T$ multiplied to it and the limits will change. The first term will be zero for every function with time period equal to $2\pi$. But in standard books the relation is valid for all functions, how?

Comment: Let us view your post properly using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: added an example of latex

Comment: @Joker Your way of trying to format mathematical formulae was almost impossible to read. Apart from the very simpliest formulae trying to use plain ascii or even extended-ascii is doomed to fail into a misserable incomprehencible ball of mud. If you want to participate here I suggest that you take the time to learn at least the very basic of MathJax formatting, with time you will get better at using it.

Answer (score 1):

For continuous functions it should be obvious since $f(0) = f(1)$ and $e^{-i2n\pi 1} = e^{-i2n\pi 0}=1$ which means that the first term will cancel out.

The case of a non-continuous function complicates things a bit, but we can do the integration over **any** interval of length $1$ and for this to me meaningful $f$ must be derivable and therefore continuous almost everywhere so we can certainly find an interval so that $f$ is continuous at the endpoint (and the first term will therefore cancel anyway).

To put it in formula language we have:

$$c_n = \int_0^1 f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t} dt = \int_0^\tau f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t} dt + \int_\tau^1f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t} dt \\
= \int_1^{\tau+1}f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t} dt + \int_\tau^1f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t}dt \\
= \int_\tau^{\tau}f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t} dt \\
= \left.f(t)e^{-2in\pi t}\right\vert_{t=\tau}^{1+\tau}+{2i\pi}\int_\tau^{\tau}f'(t) e^{-2in\pi t} dt 
$$

For any $\tau$ where $f$ is continouos at $\tau$. Therefore the first term becomes because $f(1+\tau) = f(\tau)$:

$$f(\tau+1)e^{-2in\pi(\tau+1)} - f(\tau)e^{-2in\pi\tau} 
= f(\tau+1)e^{-2in\pi}e^{-2in\pi\tau} - f(\tau)e^{-2in\pi\tau} \\
\left(f(\tau+1)-f(\tau)\right) e^{-2in\pi\tau} = 0$$